# php Xcart Setup using smarty template

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

i want to run a existing product store site on my localhost wamp server i changed all the Config variables in config file
as follow

```
$sql_host ='localhost';
$sql_user ='root';
$sql_db ='beauty';
$sql_password ='';
$xcart_http_host ="http://localhost/beautyuniverse/";
$xcart_https_host ="http://localhost/beautyuniverse/";
$xcart_web_dir ="";
```

but there is nothing showing on running my application only pure blank page is showing
All are most Welcome to solve my problem . thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing a blank page is because the PHP generated an error (maybe due to incorrect validation) and execution is halted.

To see the error, you can try to either change the configuration in `php.ini` to display errors or try to change the error reporting settings in PHP by adding the following lines at the very beginning of the file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // report all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // display errors to browser
```

You can find in the manual more information about error reporting:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Once you identify the error, you can try to fix it.

Comment: @G10DRA: Please do the same settings inside your php.ini as well and additionally enable error logging. Then check your error log. If that still does not help, look into the execution of your script with a step-debugger like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). That normally shows you the cause of the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (blank page) after moving the cart to a different server.  I had to turn on DEVELOPMENT MODE inside X-Cart and crank up the debug mode to 3 (log & write errors to screen).

Inside config.php, look for debug_mode flag and set it to 3.

`$debug_mode = 3`

And uncomment this line:

`define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for getting blank page in x-cart, besides PHP error, could be the existence of a 3rd-party module in the store, which works either based on a domain-related licence (licenced to work only on the client's domain), or requires IonCube software, in case it's code is encrypted. You can install IonCube in your local server as well and thus run the site, but you won't be able to trace it's code via a debugger.